# Repetir una funcion cada cierto tiempo en C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Tengo un problema en un pequeño videojuego que estoy intentando programar. Soy novato y he seguido un manual por Youtube.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
{
public GameObject enemyPrefab;
public float generatorTimer = Random.Range (1.75f, 5f); //Tiempo en el que se genera cada enemigo


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

void CreateEnemy()
{
    Instantiate(enemyPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);  
}

public void StartGenerator()
{
    Invoke("CreateEnemy", generatorTimer);
}
```

Lo que estoy intentando es que el **Invoke** se repita cada cierto tiempo, he probado con el **InvokeRepeating** pero al utilizarlo, el Random del generatorTimer se repite siempre el mismo valor, no va variando, que es lo que quiero.

Espero ayuda, Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Como necesitamos que el valor sea diferente en cada llamada, el tiempo lo obtenemos mejor en la llamada a la función. Y para que se repita, dentro de la misma función podemos hacer que se autoinvoque y así pasarle un valor nuevo. Al hacer la función se autoinvoque incluso puedes añadirle lógica para que deje de hacerlo.

```
{
public GameObject enemyPrefab;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

void CreateEnemy()
{
    Instantiate(enemyPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    Invoke("CreateEnemy", Random.Range (1.75f, 5f));
}

public void StartGenerator()
{
    Invoke("CreateEnemy", Random.Range (1.75f, 5f));
}
```